# SSH (or other remote access) in Windows 7 outside session 0

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin

I would like to connect to Windows 7 remotely from script (run from Linux) and be able to execute GUI commands (i.e. command that access the display device). What is the easiest way of achiving it (I tried cygwin+openssh but it is in session 0).

Comment: What do you mean by 'GUI Commands'? Run a program which interacts with other GUI programs? Send keypresses to other GUI programs? Move the mouse?

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Program accessing display devices (for example - opens a window).